# How remove "recent comments" title without modifying code?

Tags: posts, customization, title

How remove "recent comments" title without modifying code? I have already disabled comments and do not wish to see that title.

[image]

Comment: You can use css or javascript source to remove this in the visible page without change code on your theme. You should find a lot of help via googling about this.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like that's the Recent Comments widget in your sidebar.  If so, go to Appearance -> Widgets in your site's admin and either delete the Recent Comments widget or drag it to the Inactive Widgets area.